# Is there anything like GAC in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: version-control, windows-phone-7, gac, strongname, snk

If not, then how should we handle the assembly version thing?

BTW: I can not find a way to strong name sign a WP7 assembly, did I miss anything?

Comment: Is this question about the Library DLL's of WP7 you create or the WP7 app itself ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no GAC or equivalent in WP7.

The GAC is used for sharing versioned assemblies. In Windows Phone 7, each application is completely isolated from all other applications, so there is no need for an assembly sharing facility.

Comment: thanks, if there are two apps that both use A.dll, then there will be two copies of A.dll in the phone, is that correct?

Comment: AFAIK two apps cannot share a single assembly. This is because the XAP files for each app will be installed in its own private folder, with no way to access anything outside of its own `IsolatedStorage` area. So, if each app packages A.dll in its own XAP file there will be two copies of that file on the phone.