# Is it possible to share a dll between two applications in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dll, assemblies

I am new to WP7!
My question is,Is it possible in wp7 to share a dll or a library between two separate applications.
If yes,How?

Comment: Check this out. 2 apps can not share assemblies in WP7

[SO][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335111/is-there-anything-like-gac-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: Dublicate as pointed out by @Sandeep.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no GAC in WP7, each application is isolated and needs It's own copy of the assembly.